# Window.location.href(url). how to catch the success event for the url

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to make a cordova wrapper for a hosted web App. I need to catch the event for server error for the requested URL. Remember i am opening the URL by using Window.location.href. Please suggest ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it using `window.location.href`.
You can send a `GET` request using Ajax and see what status code you get back before actually going to that website.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open('GET', 'http://www.example.org', true);  
req.send();  
if (req.status != "200") {
    //  Error
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adriani6. So to achieve this we need to make GET request just to check the status before opening it with window.location.href. I guess is the only way then.